# wxpython.how to display buttons label in the textctrl area using only one function and store the value to calculate something?

Tags: wxpython

I am trying to make a calculator using wxpython.I want to display the buttons label in the textctrl area and use the value to calculate something.Can I do it using only one function?And how can I store the value to use it.Like when I press 7+8 it will display 7+8 and when I press "ans" button it will calculate 15.I've tried a program.But it's saying- 
                     "invalid literal for int() with base 10: '7+'"

```
import wx

class Calculator(wx.Frame):
def __init__(self,parent,id):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,"Calculator",size=(300,400))
    self.panel=wx.Panel(self,wx.ID_ANY)
    self.stext=wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,-1,pos=(10,10),size=(260,50))
    self.stext.SetBackgroundColour('GRAY')
    b=wx.Button(self.panel,-1,'7',pos=(10,70),size=(30,30))
    b1=wx.Button(self.panel,-1,'8',pos=(60,70),size=(30,30))
    b2=wx.Button(self.panel,-1,'9',pos=(110,70),size=(30,30))
    b3=wx.Button(self.panel,-1,'+',pos=(160,70),size=(100,30))
    b4=wx.Button(self.panel,-1,'4',pos=(10,120),size=(30,30))
    b5=wx.Button(self.panel,-1,'5',pos=(60,120),size=(30,30))
    b6=wx.Button(self.panel,-1,'6',pos=(110,120),size=(30,30))
    b7= wx.Button(self.panel,-1,'-',pos=(160,120),size=(100,30))
    b8=wx.Button(self.panel,-1,'1',pos=(10,170),size=(30,30))
    b9=wx.Button(self.panel,-1,'2',pos=(60,170),size=(30,30))
    b10=wx.Button(self.panel,-1,'3',pos=(110,170),size=(30,30))
    b11=wx.Button(self.panel,-1,'*',pos=(160,170),size=(100,30))
    b12=wx.Button(self.panel,-1,'.',pos=(10,220),size=(30,30))
    b13=wx.Button(self.panel,-1,'0',pos=(60,220),size=(30,30))
    b14=wx.Button(self.panel,-1,'Ans',pos=(110,220),size=(30,30))
    b15=wx.Button(self.panel,-1,'/',pos=(160,220),size=(100,30))


    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.seven,b)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.eight,b1)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.plus,b3)
    #self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.minus,b7)
    #self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.multi,b11)
    #self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.divide,b15)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.equal,b14)

def seven(self,event):
    label = event.GetEventObject().GetLabel()
    self.stext.AppendText(label)

def eight(self,event):
    label = event.GetEventObject().GetLabel()
    self.stext.AppendText(label)

def plus(self,event):
    self.c=0
    label = event.GetEventObject().GetLabel()
    self.stext.AppendText(label)
    self.one=(int(self.stext.GetValue()))  #first value will be stored here

def equal(self,event):
    if self.c==0:
       self.two=(int(self.stext.GetValue()))  #second value will be stored here
       plus=self.one+self.two                 
       self.stext.SetValue(str(plus))

app=wx.App()
frame=Calculator(None,-1)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of approaches you can take. The harder of the two will be to create a parser for the value in `self.stext`. However this will also be the most flexible method, depending on how complex your calculator becomes. The easier method would be to use Python's `eval` builtin. Some people say that eval is dangerous as it can execute arbitrary code (which is true), but since you will control what goes into the text control, you should be able to keep anything bad from happening. If you use eval, then you can just do something like this:

```
answer = eval( self.stext.GetValue() )
```

For more information, please see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval).